# Portable Shortcuts on Windows

Tags: windows, shortcuts

I can't figure out how to create shortcuts that don't care where they are mounted.  For example, on my flash drive, I want to run CCleaner or Notepad++ in my college classroom.  The problem is, a shortcut (at least with default settings) doesn't work reliably because it is tied to the same drive it was created on.  Is there a way to do something like in HTML?

Example:

Here is where the actual program is:

```
Root\Portable Applications\Program Data\CCleaner\ccleaner.exe
```

Here is where I want the shortcut to be:

```
Root\Portable Applications\CCleaner.lnk
```

U3/Portable Apps/etc is not the solution I am looking for

Edit: The Versions of Windows will be XP 32 bit, Vista 64 bit, and Vista 32 bit

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [mklink](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753194%28WS.10%29.aspx) if on Vista or later to create symbolic links. They can be pointed to wherever you want. Alternatively a batch file as pointed out by `pelms` would work as well.

Comment: Hi John, thank you for your reply.  When I try to use mklink, I get the error message, "The device does not support symbolic links."  After a quick search, mklink isn't for FAT filesystems.  If there are no other options, I will switch to NTFS for my thumb drive.  Thank you again John for your answer.

Comment: Junctions are not the same as symlinks. Junctions can only point to directories, and work in a different way. Real Unix-like symlinks were added only in Vista.

Answer (score 9):

Instead of using a shortcut you could create a batch file that uses a root relative path to the exe file.
e.g. for your example

```
@start "" "\Portable Applications\Program Data\CCleaner\ccleaner.exe"
```

The batch file should then work from anywhere on the USB drive, whatever the drive letter.

Comment: You can even change the icon if you want. don't know the portability of that.

Comment: @Dykam. Can you change the icon for a .bat file without using Dan's method..?

Answer (score 4):

Ok thank you guys for your replies.  Here is what I ended up doing for any interested.  pelms idea to use a batch file is almost it.  (A Very good idea, thank you pelms)  What I did was just make an AutoIt script that runs the apps in directories below it.  Then I just compiled it with an extracted .ico from each executable file so everything looked pretty.  Thanks again John and pelmsd

```
Run ('Program Data\PDF X-Change\PDFXCview.exe')
```

That is all the script consists of.  Thanks again guys, I have linked the two programs I used if anyone is interested

[AutoIt](http://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/index.shtml)

[IcoFX](http://icofx.ro/)

Answer (score 0):

You can put the following in the shortcut Target:

`C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /c "start ./foo.bar"`

However the Icon will be the `cmd` icon.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).