# Windows - Relative shortcut path to .exe

Tags: windows, shortcuts, path

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Portable Shortcuts on Windows](https://superuser.com/questions/28115/portable-shortcuts-on-windows)

How to create a realtive shortcut path under Windows? Currently the path is `"C:\myfolder\example.exe"`- I tried the following but there comes an error message *invalid path*: `"myfolder\example.exe"`

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Windows shortcuts do not use relative paths. They are pointers to specific files and folders on your system.

Go to the Properties of any shortcut (.lnk) file. In the "shortcut" tab, you will see the "Target" field, which always contains the full path to the resource.

Comment: And there is no workaround? Creating a bat file? Creating an exe to execute the relative path?