# Workaround to create a "link" to a relative path

Tags: symbolic-link

I've got a zip file in which is presente a folder containing another subfolder containing the executable.

I would like to create a link to the executable but links take only absolute path..

So I need a workaround.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/28115/portable-shortcuts-on-windows

Answer (score 0):

The question has already been answered here: [Windows - Relative shortcut path to .exe](https://superuser.com/questions/525707/windows-relative-shortcut-path-to-exe)

I will post this question anyway since it will be easier to find.